# Compiling MFC application with /clr (step1: linking against dynamic DLLs)

Tags: mfc, clr, linker, afx

I have successfully upgraded an MFC application which was compiled with an old version of Developer Studio to Visual Studio 2008. A very small number of changes were needed because of some breaking changes in MFC. Now that everything works, I'd like to take the next step and compile the solution with `/clr`.

To do so, I have found useful information on the MSDN web site:

- [How to: Migrate to /clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173265(VS.80).aspx)
- [How to: Compile MFC and ATL Code with /clr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235211(VS.80).aspx)

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Set the **Runtime Library** to **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**.
2. Set the **Use of MFC** to **Use MFC in a Shared DLL**.

However, doing so prevents me from linking the project:

1. The reference to `afxData` can no longer be resolved; somehow, `afxData` is only visible when linking statically against MFC. In my code, I have the following declaration:

   `extern AFX_DATA AUX_DATA afxData;`

   which works fine with the statically linked MFC version.
2. The references to `_afxThreadState` and `_afxWinState` cannot be resolved either.

Here are the full error messages :

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct AUX_DATA afxData" (?afxData@@3UAUX_DATA@@A)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CThreadLocal<class _AFX_THREAD_STATE> _afxThreadState" (?_afxThreadState@@3V?$CThreadLocal@V_AFX_THREAD_STATE@@@@A)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class CProcessLocal<class _AFX_WIN_STATE> _afxWinState" (?_afxWinState@@3V?$CProcessLocal@V_AFX_WIN_STATE@@@@A)
```

in case this might be related to the name mangling...

So, what can I do in order to dynamically link against MFC, but still reference `afxData`, `_afxThreadState` and `_afxWinState`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using MFC in a shared DLL, AUX_DATA must be `dllimport`ed.

```
extern __declspec(dllimport) AUX_DATA afxData
```

For thread state, rather than using template classes, use one of these

```
AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE* pState = _AFX_CMDTARGET_GETSTATE()->m_thread;
AFX_THREAD_STATE* pState = AfxGetThreadState();
```

Depending on the state information you require. For example, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sc4t4k(vs.80).aspx) for some members that were moved to module state to fix a bug. Note that AfxGetModuleThreadState exists but is undocumented and could be changed in a future version.

Win state does not ring a bell, how is it used? There is probably a new way to accomplish it.

Comment: Thank you for the hints; here are my first results at trying to solve this: AfxGetThreadState() seems to replace the previous use of _afxThreadState.
I should have thought of the __declspec(dllimport) myself! I tried it and it works.
I'll further investigate the _afxWinState thing. It points to a _AFX_WIN_STATE class which has a single member, m_bUserAbort, which is used by our code while printing, to check if the user pressed Cancel, I guess from what I see.

Comment: The afxWinState.m_bUserAbort is a design mistake made by Microsoft, from what I understand reading this article: http://www.ddj.com/184409908?pgno=5
The solution is to replace that code completely by using a global flag in our own code and by rewriting the default AbortProc.

Comment: Added some clarification. There are some situations where you may want Module thread state.